# Docker Wordpress - Wrong URL

Tags: docker

So I followed the tutorial on this page https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/. Here is the two files I ended up creating and the directory structure

```
~/project
    Dockerfile
    docker-compose.yml
    wordpress
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM orchardup/php5
ADD . /wordpress
```

docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  build: .
  command: php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 -t /wordpress
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  links:
    - db
  volumes:
    - .:/wordpress
db:
  image: orchardup/mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
```

When I try to load up the URL in the browser I get an error

[image: Error Message]

Container logs

```
[Sat Dec  5 22:32:38 2015] 192.168.99.1:64220 [404]: / - No such file or directory
[Sat Dec  5 22:33:16 2015] 192.168.99.1:64235 [404]: / - No such file or directory
[Sat Dec  5 22:33:45 2015] 192.168.99.1:64243 [404]: / - No such file or directory
[Sat Dec  5 22:33:45 2015] 192.168.99.1:64244 [404]: /favicon.ico - No such file or directory
[Sat Dec  5 22:33:50 2015] 192.168.99.1:64248 [404]: /wp-admin - No such file or directory
[Sat Dec  5 22:35:08 2015] 192.168.99.1:64249 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
[Sat Dec  5 22:35:08 2015] 192.168.99.1:64250 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
[Sat Dec  5 22:35:08 2015] 192.168.99.1:64251 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
[Sat Dec  5 22:44:22 2015] 192.168.99.1:64361 [404]: / - No such file or directory
[Sat Dec  5 22:44:25 2015] 192.168.99.1:64366 [404]: / - No such file or directory
[Sat Dec  5 22:50:00 2015] 192.168.99.1:64442 [404]: / - No such file or directory
[Sat Dec  5 22:50:16 2015] 192.168.99.1:64443 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
[Sat Dec  5 22:50:16 2015] 192.168.99.1:64444 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
[Sat Dec  5 22:51:30 2015] 192.168.99.1:64477 [404]: / - No such file or directory
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. What is the actual question or error here? Did you create the `wp-config.php` file?

Comment: I just updated post with more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the current directory to `/wordpress` inside the image. So, the location of the Wordpress files is at `/wordpress/wordpress`. If you are starting up PHP with a document root of `/wordpress` then you will want navigate to http://192.168.99.100:8000/wordpress.